# How can I edit a css class in Chrome that only appears when I drag something?

Tags: css, angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

In my website project, an element only changes style when I drag something over it. It does this by adding a CSS class to it.

The problem is that I have a hard time editing this style because I can't live edit it in Chrome. I have to edit the file, reload the webpage, then drag something to see the changes.

Is there any way to do this just inside Chrome? Most magically, would be if there was some way to *freeze* my dragging and then be able to edit. Anything close?

Comment: Just put the style on a static element first.... then use the style on the draggable element when you are happy with it....?

Answer (score 1):

- Browse to the desired page
- Open console (F12)
- Select 'SOURCES' tab in chrome inspector
- Drag the element
- Hit F8 to freeze (if you have clicked anywhere on the actual page F8
  will do nothing, your last click needed to be somewhere in the inspector, like the sources tab)
- Go back to elements tab in inspector
- It should now be nested in the trigger element's html

Comment: How can my last click be in the inspector if I have to click on the item I want to drag?

Comment: Could this help?:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540379/inspect-helper-clone

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick:

in Google Chrome *Console* type at any time you want to test that class

```
var elm = document.getElementById('yourElementId'); elm.classList.add('yourClassToTest');
```

*(please note: you have to press SWIFT+ENTER if you like to create a new line break in Google Chrome Console)*

At this point you have added the class you want to test on the div.
Just use the web inspector, in order to change/inspect any CSS properties.

This solution lets you avoid to manually  drag something to see your class/changes.